# Update an array by mapping over two array of objects by matching fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an arrays of objects with the following structure:

```
let source1 = [
  {
    s1prop1: "val1",
    s1prop2: ["test1", "test2"]
  },
  {
    s1prop1: "val2",
    s1prop2: []
  }
];

let source2 = [
  {
    s2prop1: "test1",
    s2prop2: "finalVal1"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test2",
    s2prop2: "finalVal2"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test3",
    s2prop2: "finalVal3"
  }
];
```

Basically need to iterate over the `source1` and then based on items of `s1prop2` array , need to pick the corresponding `s2prop2` from second array of objects i.e., `source2` and then update `source1` with the matched value. If the value of `s1prop2` is empty array , skip it. The resultant array of object should look like

```
let result = [
  {
    s1prop1: "val1",
    //fetching the s2prop2 value from source2 based on s1prop1 array items by matching s2prop1, i.e.,test1 and test2 
    s1prop2: ["finalVal1", "finalVal2"]
  },
  {
    s1prop1: "val2",
    s1prop2: []
  }
];
```

What I tried:

```
let result = source1.map((e, i) => {
  let temp = source2.find((element) => element === e.s2prop1);
  return e;
});
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with both `ecmascript-6` and `ecmascript-5`. Which version of ECMAScript are you targeting? Please [edit] your question and remove the version of ECMAScript you are not targeting.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do. What is the criteria for constructing the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map over the `s1prop2` array in the source element, and use that to construct the `s1prop2` property in the result element by searching for the corresponding element of `source2`.

```js
let source1 = [{
    s1prop1: "val1",
    s1prop2: ["test1", "test2"]
  },
  {
    s1prop1: "val2",
    s1prop2: []
  }
];

let source2 = [{
    s2prop1: "test1",
    s2prop2: "finalVal1"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test2",
    s2prop2: "finalVal2"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test3",
    s2prop2: "finalVal3"
  }
];

let result = source1.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  s1prop2: obj.s1prop2.map(p => source2.find(el => el.s2prop1 == p).s2prop2)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Things would be much easier if `source2` were an object that uses the `s2prop1` values as property names, rather than an array that has to be searched.

Comment: what if there are multiple properties in source1, here I see you are destructuring s1prop1 and s1prop2. What If I have few other properties along with these two?

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question that this was a possibility or that all the properties other than `s1prop2` need to be copied.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use spread syntax to merge the new `s1prop2` property into a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change every value of the array with the corresponding  one o the second array:

```
let result = source1.map((e, i) => {
    e.s1prop2 = e.s1prop2.map( o => {
        return (source2.find((element) => element.s2prop1 === o) || {}).s2prop2 || null;
    })
    return e;
});
```

```js
let source1 = [
  {
    s1prop1: "val1",
    s1prop2: ["test1", "test2"]
  },
  {
    s1prop1: "val2",
    s1prop2: []
  }
];

let source2 = [
  {
    s2prop1: "test1",
    s2prop2: "finalVal1"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test2",
    s2prop2: "finalVal2"
  },
  {
    s2prop1: "test3",
    s2prop2: "finalVal3"
  }
];
let result = source1.map((e, i) => {
    e.s1prop2 = e.s1prop2.map( o => {
        return (source2.find((element) => element.s2prop1 === o) || {}).s2prop2 || null;
    })
    return e;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the grouped objects.

```js
let source1 = [  {    s1prop1: "val1",    s1prop2: ["test1", "test2"]  },  {    s1prop1: "val2",    s1prop2: []  }],
    source2 = [  {    s2prop1: "test1",    s2prop2: "finalVal1"  },  {    s2prop1: "test2",    s2prop2: "finalVal2"  },  {    s2prop1: "test3",    s2prop2: "finalVal3"  }],
    result = Object.values(source1.reduce((r, {s1prop1, s1prop2}) => {
      let properties = source2.reduce((a, {s2prop1, s2prop2}) => s1prop2.includes(s2prop1) ? a.concat(s2prop2) : a, []);
      (r[s1prop1] || (r[s1prop1] = {s1prop1, s1prop2: []})).s1prop2.push(...properties);
      return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```